# Laravel job dispatcher not using Queue

Tags: php, laravel-5, message-queue

I am trying to dispatch jobs in Laravel into redis. If I do

```
Queue::push('LogMessage', array('message' => 'Time: '.time()));
```

then a job is placed into the `queues:default` key in redis. (note that I do not yet have the listener running; I'm just trying to show that the queue is being used.) However, if I do

```
$this->dispatch(new AudienceMetaReportJob(1));
```

then nothing is added to redis and the job executes immediately.

The Job definition:

```
<?php

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

/**
 * Simple Job used to build an Audience Report. Its purpose is to
 * allow code to dispatch the command to build the report.
 */
class AudienceMetaReportJob extends Job {
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    protected $audience_id;

    /**
     * @param $audience_id
     */
    public function __construct($audience_id){
        $this->audience_id = $audience_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(){
        $audience_meta = new AudienceMeta();
        $audience_meta->reportable = Audience::findOrFail($this->audience_id);
        $audience_meta->clear()
            ->build()
            ->save();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The Audience job appears to complete properly, but does so *as if the QUEUE_DRIVER env variable was set to sync*
- Redis has been configured properly, as I can manually use the Queue:push() function and can read from redis
- I have set the QUEUE_DRIVER env variable to redis, and the problem exists even if I hardcode redis in the config/queue.php file: `'default' => 'redis',`
- I do not have `php artisan queue:listen` running

What other configuration am I missing? Why does the Queue class work with redis, while the dispatch function does not?